# SQL Joining 2 Tables with Distinct Values

Tags: sql

I'm looking to join 2 tables together: dash and mv. They both contain identical columns with some overlapping values in batch_id. They both reference mes,mes2 tables just fine.

My code currently joins the two tables but duplicates still remain:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  dash.batch_id
  , dash.atf_id
  , dash.phase
  , dash.model_used
  , CASE WHEN dash.atf_id like 'ATF1' THEN mes.atf1_id ELSE 
mes.atf2_id END as controller
  , mes.uf_start
  , mes2.uf_start as baseline_start
FROM dash, mes, mes2
WHERE dash.batch_id = mes.batchid AND dash.model_used = mes2.batchid

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT 
  mv.batch_id
  , mv.atf_id
  , mv.phase
  , mv.model_used
  , CASE WHEN mv.atf_id like 'ATF1' THEN mes.atf1_id ELSE mes.atf2_id 
END as controller
  , mes.uf_start
  , mes2.uf_start as baseline_start
FROM mv, mes, mes2
WHERE mv.batch_id = mes.batchid
  AND mv.model_used = mes2.batchid
```

Both chunks seem to work individually (chunk above without the UNION, or chunk below without the UNION). Ideally, I would like to merge the two such that duplicates of batch_id are removed.

Im thinking that a left-join might be more appropriate.

- If mv.batch_id=dash.batch_id AND mv.phase=dash.phase AND ....
- Then only bring over dash values

Thanks!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax rather then the archaic commas that do implicit Cartesian products.

Comment: The requirements are unclear.  It's helpful to provide test data and expected results, based on that test data.  Clearly define the concept of `MERGE` when there are cases of matching `batch_id`, and relate that to the expected result provided.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using Union, the number of expressions in both in both select statement must be same.
UNION statement removes duplicates by default

Comment: For the OP: To clarify your first select has 6 values returned, the second select has 7 values returned which is why UNION is not acting as expected.

Comment: I just updated the question a bit, but i am thinking that maybe a left join may be more appropriate. So if the batch_id, atf_id, phase, controller of dash matches that of mv, then i only want to bring over dash data.

Comment: Sorry, that was poor c/p. There is 7 values. I was trying to trim my code a bit to capture bare elements